# Updating the PATH environment variable in Windows using C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process

I am trying to launch a new process from my current process. I am using CreateProcess() to launch it. The issue is that I need to have certain directories in my PATH to successfully do so. Here is my current implementation but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
// Environment variables
char *env = new char[2048];
char *ptr = env;

char temp[MAX_PATH] = "PATH=";
strcpy(ptr, strcat(temp, plugin_path));
ptr += strlen(ptr) + 1;

char  temp2[MAX_PATH] = "PATH=";
strcpy(ptr, strcat(temp, lib_path));
ptr += strlen(ptr) + 1;
*ptr = '\0';

 // Execute
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

// error checking required
if(!CreateProcess(
    NULL,             // application name
    command_path,   // app.exe
    NULL,
    NULL,
    TRUE,
    0,
    env,           // environment
    NULL,
    &si,
    &pi)) {
    std::cout << GetLastError();
    return 1;
}

WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
std::cout << "Process Started!";
```

Please let me know if anything else is required.

EDIT: Somebody mentioned below that I need to be a little more specific. It doesn't work in the sense that the environment variables don't get passed. It fails because the library path is not in PATH. The createProcess does actually launch it though.

EDIT2: Here's the updated code. Same problem. Further, CreateProcess throws error 1087 which doesn't seem to exist in the docs.

```
// Environment variables
char env[2048];
char *ptr = env;
char *path_path = getenv("PATH");

// copy original path
memcpy(ptr, path_path, strlen(path_path));
ptr += strlen(ptr) + 1;
memcpy(ptr, ";", 1);
ptr++;

// copy plugin path
memcpy(ptr, plugin_path, strlen(plugin_path));
ptr += strlen(plugin_path) + 1;
memcpy(ptr, ";", 1);
ptr++;

// copy libpath
memcpy(ptr, lib_path, strlen(lib_path));
ptr += strlen(lib_path) + 1;
memcpy(ptr, ";", 1);
ptr++;

// double null terminated
memcpy(ptr, "\0\0", 2);

std::cout << "ENV : " << env << std::endl;

// error checking required
if(!CreateProcess(
    NULL,             // application name
    command_path,   // app.exe
    NULL,
    NULL,
    TRUE,
    0,
    env,           // environment
    NULL,
    &si,
    &pi)) {
    std::cout << GetLastError();
    return 1;
}

WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
std::cout << "Process Started!";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `PATH` variable is a single variable. Different directories are listed in that variable, separated by semi-colons. But you've attempted to define the variable twice. That is the mistake.

The code should be something like this (assuming that you want to extend the existing path):

```
char *env = new char[2048]; // fingers crossed this is enough
strcpy(env, "PATH=");
strcat(env, getenv("PATH"));
strcat(env, ";");
strcat(env, plugin_path);
strcat(env, ";");
strcat(env, lib_path);
env[strlen(env)+1] = '\0';
```

Although this code (as is yours in the question) is simply begging for a buffer overrun.

It would be so much easier if you used C++ facilities to build your strings. For instance:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "PATH=" << getenv("PATH");
ss << ";" << plugin_path;
ss << ";" << lib_path;
ss << '\0';
std::string env = ss.str();
```

Then pass `env.c_str()` to `CreateProcess`.

Not only does this make the code easier to read and verify, you know that you won't overrun any buffers.

I also note that you are passing an environment that has only one variable defined in it, namely `PATH`. It might be better if you started from the environment of the calling process, added the extra directories to `PATH`, and then passed that as the environment for the new process.

Comment: I was unaware that it is possible to use ";" like that. I will try what you said and report back!

Comment: I was unable to do it. I have updated the question with my latest attempt.

Comment: Now your pointer arithmetic is screwed up. If you'd used my code you'd have been fine. Perhaps now is the time to switch to std::string. Wait and I will show you.

Comment: I'm not permitted to use std::string. I will try to figure this out. Thanks nevertheless. EDIT: Alright! Thanks.

Comment: 'env[strlen(env)] = '\0';' <- Does this line add the second null character to make it double null terminated or should I add another one after that like 'env[strlen(env) + 1] = '\0';' ?

Comment: @ChromoZoneX Silly error by me. Should be `env[strlen(env)+1] = '\0';` D'oh!! This is why you should use `std::string`!

Comment: That still doesn't seem to work. I'm unsure if the problem is with building the string or actually passing it now.

Comment: Do some debugging. Print the environment that you make. Do bear in mind that you are passing a seriously crippled environment that only has one variable. Does the other program really work with no variables other than `PATH` defined? I'm pretty sure I answered the question that you asked. I don't think it's quite fair to expect me to write all the rest of your code?!  ;-)

Comment: Thanks :) Filler to comment.

Comment: Thanks for the accept. Your next step is to print out the environment and check that is is appropriate. I can see that you tried that. Your latest attempt was broken because instead of `ptr += strlen(ptr) + 1` you needed ptr += strlen(ptr)` etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstring>
#include "tchar.h"


void SetUserVariablePath(){
    HKEY hkey;
    long regOpenResult;
    const char key_name[] = "Environment";
    const char path[]="D:/custom_command";                                               //new_value path need to update 
    regOpenResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,key_name, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hkey);
    LPCSTR stuff = "VVS_LOGGING_PATH";                                                   //Variable Name 
    RegSetValueEx(hkey,stuff,0,REG_SZ,(BYTE*) path, strlen(path));
    RegCloseKey(hkey);
}



void GetUserVariablePath(){
    static const char path[] = "VVS_LOGGING_PATH" ;                                      //Variable Name 
    static BYTE buffer1[1000000] ;
    DWORD buffsz1 = sizeof(buffer1) ;
    {
        //HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
        const char key_name[] = "Environment";
        HKEY key ;

        if( RegOpenKeyExA( HKEY_CURRENT_USER, key_name, 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, std::addressof(key) ) == 0 &&
            RegQueryValueExA( key, path, nullptr, nullptr, buffer1, std::addressof(buffsz1) ) == 0 )
        {
            std::cout << "The updated value of the user variable is :  " << reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buffer1) << '\n' ;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{   
    SetUserVariablePath();
    GetUserVariablePath();
    return 0;
}
```